# How do you specify multiple AppleScript child elements of the same class?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I'm adding Apple Event scripting to my application. I would like to be able to use both of the statements below on it:

```
-- Every instance of MyObject in the app
every MyObject

-- Only the instances of MyObject the user has selected
selected MyObjects
```

These are relevant excerpts from of my `sdef` file:

```
<dictionary>
    <suite ...>
        <class name="application" code="capp" description="Top-level scripting object" plural="applications" inherits="application">
            <cocoa class="MyAppClass" />

            <element type="MyObject" access="r">
                <cocoa key="myobjects" />
            </element>

            <element name="selected MyObjects" code="ABCD" type="MyObject" access="rw">
                <cocoa key="selectedMyObjects" />
            </element>
        </class>

        <class name="MyObject" code="ABcd" inherits="item" plural="MyObjects">
        ...
        </class>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

When I call `every MyObject`, it returns a list of objects, as expected. But when I call `selected MyObjects`, the Script Editor selects the "MyObjects" portion and complains:

> **Syntax Error**
>
> Expected end of line, etc. but found plural class name.

How can I achieve what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is wrong. See the [Scripting Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2002/tn2106.html) for a somewhat thin but better-than-nothing outline of good UX practices.

The correct idiom is to define a `selection` property, typically on `application` and/or `document`. This may be read-write or read-only, depending on what's appropriate to your application.

The `selection` property's value is either:

1. A single bespoke object specifier that identifies all of the currently selected objects e.g.:

   ```
   selection of application "Foo"
   ```

   or

   ```
   selection of document X of application "Foo"
   ```

   Some of the better Carbon-based apps and the occasional Cocoa app use this approach, which allows users to perform powerful queries such as:

   ```
   get (name of every MyObject of selection of document X)

   delete (every job whose status is completed)
   ```

   but requires more work for you to implement.
2. A list of single-object specifiers, each identifying one selected item, e.g.:

   ```
   {thing B of document X of application "Foo", 
    thing E of document X of application "Foo",...}
   ```

   This is less powerful, since users cannot manipulate all of the selected items in a single command but must instead iterate the list processing each item one at a time, but is cheaper for you to implement. Cocoa Scripting being somewhat lame and inflexible even at the best of times, and pretty damn hopeless at moving/duplicating/deleting more than one object at a time, this is the most common approach in Cocoa-based apps.

   Update your `sdef` file with this property:

   ```
   <property name="selection" code="ABCD">
       <cocoa key="selectedMyObjects" />
       <type type="MyObject" list="yes" />
   </property>
   ```

For an example of the first (better) design approach, take a look at Script Editor's own dictionary. For an example of the second, see Mail's dictionary.

(Tip: To view a dictionary in Script Editor, choose File>Open Dictionary and select the appropriate item from the list. To export that dictionary as an SDEF file, just make sure the dictionary viewer window is frontmost and choose File>Save As.)