# AppleScript error for property, not for element

Tags: macos, cocoa, scripting, applescript

When I make the following AppleScript call to my app, I get a list of text objects:

```
tell "MyApp"
    name of every myobject
end tell
```

But the following call returns an error:

```
tell "MyApp"
    name of selected myobjects
end tell
```

> **Script Error**
>
> MyApp got an error: Can't make name of selected MyObjects into type specifier.

I turned on verbose logging with the `-NSScriptingDebugLogLevel 1` argument to my app, which gave me this:

```
2015-01-27 14:33:53.650 MyApp[4848:2572448] Error converting apple event to script command: -1700
2015-01-27 14:33:53.650 MyApp[4848:2572448]     Original event: <NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'core'\'getd'{ '----':'obj '{ 'form':'prop', 'want':'prop', 'seld':'pnam', 'from':'obj '{ 'form':'prop', 'want':'prop', 'seld':'MASM', 'from':null() } }, &'csig':65536 }>
2015-01-27 14:33:53.650 MyApp[4848:2572448]     Offending object descriptor: <NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'obj '{ 'form':'prop', 'want':'prop', 'seld':'pnam', 'from':'obj '{ 'form':'prop', 'want':'prop', 'seld':'MASM', 'from':null() } }>
2015-01-27 14:33:53.651 MyApp[4848:2572448]     Expected type descriptor: <NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'obj '>
```

This is the "application" section of my `sdef` file:

```
<class name="application" code="capp" plural="applications" inherits="application">
    <cocoa class="MyApp.MAApplication" />

    <element type="myobject" access="r">
        <cocoa key="myobjects" />
    </element>

    <property name="selected myobjects" code="MASM">
        <cocoa key="selectedMyObjects" />
        <type type="myobject" list="yes" />
    </property>
</class>
```

And the MyObject class:

```
<class name="myobject" code="MAMO" inherits="item" plural="myobjects">
    <cocoa class="MyObject" />

    <property name="id" code="ID  " type="text" access="r">
        <cocoa key="permanentID" />
    </property>

    <property name="name" code="pnam" type="text" access="r">
        <cocoa key="displayName" />
    </property>
</class>
```

When I just call `selected myobjects`, I get back a list of identifiers, so that part is working correctly. When can't I get the `name` or other properties back from that list, when I can with another list specified the exact same way (except as an `element` instead of `property`)?

**Update**

Still not having any luck so far. I noticed, with verbose logging, that when I call `name of every MyObject`, the command "Intrinsics.get" triggers with an `NSPropertySpecifier` "displayName of myobjects". Apparently that link doesn't get made when using a `property` rather than an `element` to return a list of items. I found a workaround, though, since I specify an `is selected` property on MyObject. You can call:

```
name of every myobject whose is selected = true
```

That works the way I expected my `selected myobjects` property to work, returning a list of text objects.

**Update 2**

I added a sample project to GitHub:

https://github.com/abbeycode/AppleScriptObjectList

That contains a sample script with the first two methods that behave as expected, followed by the one that triggers the error. Feel free to mess around if you'd like. I submitted [a radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5776483314302976) with this sample project.

Comment: I've updated my previous reply (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28168157/2298645) with pointers to practical examples. If you want to allow complex queries on selections, you will have to copy the approach used by Script Editor's own `selection` property, define a custom `selection-object` class and put your MyObject elements on that, then define a `selection` property containing a `selection-object` object on your `document` and/or `application` class. This will allow users to write `name of every myobject of selection`, which is how the AS syntax should look [1].

Comment: [1] (Note again that the standard name for this property is `selection`, not `selected <whatever>`. Also, I'm assuming `MyObject`/`myobject` is anonymized code, and not the actual class name. OTOH, if the Cocoa class really is named `MyObject`, you should still pick a more meaningful human-readable name to use in AppleScript code. Good scripting interface design is good user interface design.)

Comment: Yes, MyObject is anonymized. I'll take a look at how Script Editor defines its scripting dictionary.

Comment: I see now what your examples illustrate. I'm doing it the way Mail does it, and it's behaving the same way. But I was trying to use iTunes as my template, and iTunes uses `specifier` as the class. I couldn't figure out how to use that and return a list of specifiers from my app. I should basically define my own selection object, like Script Editor does, I suppose, but I'm still curious about iTunes.

Comment: iTunes is old-school. Carbon apps tend to roll their own AE handlers from scratch which can easily behave however they like; OTOH Cocoa apps build on the Cocoa Scripting framework which encourages certain idioms while making others difficult at best. While you could mimic iTunes' approach, you'll find it easier to work with CS than against it. Mind that an Apple Event Object Model is all sleight of hand anyway - a thick abstraction made up of of a simple relational query evaluator operating on a highly idealized user-facing representation of the app's true object graph. It's fun on a bun.